# USB passthrough (non storage) to XenServer 7 VM

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, citrix, passthrough, xencenter

I have migrated a server from physical to virtual using XenServer 7. Nevertheless, we need now a USB dongle for security purposes but have not been able to find the way to properly pass it to the virtual machine.

Most resources point to using USB over Ethernet, but this is not an option as we have no more hardware and this must be kept on the CPD.

There must be a way to do this. Additionally, we have another device which is connected to the old server through RS232. We have purchased an USB adapter for it and also want to passthrough it... Let's cross fingers.

I have had no problems with this in the past using Proxmox, but we are very surprised that a "more commercial" product like XenServer does not provide this mechanism out of the box.. :S

Any manual on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: These dongles and specialized cards are the only things I won't virtualize because it's a pain. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Not supported

Sorry. This has been a requested feature since 2007. And as of 2016 it is still unsupported.

You may have to buy a dedicated USB-to-Ethernet dongle server. I have no experience with these things. But they exist. E.g. from [SEH](https://www.seh-technology.com/products/usb-dongle-server.html) or from [Silex](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers&field-keywords=silex+usb+server&rh=n%3A541966%2Ck%3Asilex+usb+server).

### Sources:

- Citrix XenServer Feature Request Forum: 2007, [*USB - How to add the USB to the guest Machines*](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/153069-usb-how-to-add-the-usb-to-the-guest-machines/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/SOERz).)
- Citrix XenServer Feature Request Forum: 2014, [*XenServer USB Passthrough Support to VMs for More Than Just Storage Devices*](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/353184-xenserver-usb-passthrough-support-to-vms-for-more-than-just-storage-devices/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/G2EFA).)